# Why is my counterexample of this Theorem wrong or invalid?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand this Theorem for my mathematical analysis class, but I feel that the Theorem is wrong. Theorem: Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$  such that $x\leq y + \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $x \leq y$. Counterexample: $x=2$, $y=1$, $\varepsilon=3$. Then $2 \leq 1+3$, but clearly not $2 \leq 1$. Please help me to understand why my counterexample is wrong or invalid?

Comment: $3$ is not *every* epsilon.

Comment: You do not get to pick the epsilon! It must be for every epsilon. If on the other hand it said "there exists" an epsilon, then you would get to pick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $\varepsilon$ does not mean: No matter for what $\varepsilon$ it holds. It means: It has to hold for every epsilon. So your example fails because the condition doesnt hold for $\varepsilon=0.1$